# IPhone Key board is not responding

Tags: iphone, ios4, keyboard

In the `viewdidload` method, I've assigned one of my text fields as first responder by the following way.

```
[txtUsername becomeFirstResponder];
```

When the view gets loaded, the text field becomes active and a keyboard appears. But when I tried typing on the keyboard, it is not responding. However when I touched the text field, the keyboard is responding properly. I don't know what is wrong with this. can anyone give me a suggestion?

Thanks in Advance - Abilash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `becomeFirstResponder` in `viewDidLoad` is not a good idea because the view might not even be on the screen and part of the view hierarchy yet.

Try calling `becomeFirstResponder` in `viewDidAppear:` instead:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [txtUsername becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've added the becomeFirstResponder in viewDidAppear. but this didn't solved my problem. Still the same thing is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

check if there's any construction of Outlets in your viewDidLoad, may be some of them is called after you set tetUsername as first responder.
Also Mike Weller's answer is the most common situation of such problem.